# jquery function loading 2 pages having bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('#homemenubutton').click(function() {

            $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php');
            $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
        });




$.ajaxSetup({
                url: "pages/mayorscolumn.php",
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#leftcolumncontainer").html(result);
                }
            });
            $.ajax();
            $('#menuhome').click(function() {
            location.reload(true);
            //$('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/mayorscolumn.php');
            //$('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/imagegallerycolumn.php');
            });
```

i have this code above to load a page in left side of page this page is a menu page while the middle page will be content.my question is very simple why does it behave odd sometimes and perfectly other times..there are times when i press the button middle pages is loaded in both container there are times that it load both pages.what may cause this to happened?any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: there's nothing in that code that would cause what you describe, there must be something else going on. Use the Javascript debugger to troubleshoot it, that's what it's there for.

Comment: i get nothing on the debugger im using chrome i run the page while i run the inspect element it does not stop the page..

Comment: Quite likely you have other click event listeners. Is this all the code you have on the page? How does your markup look like?

Comment: Well, there's really no way that we can tell what's going wrong just by looking at those 4 lines of code.

Comment: Is your page accessible to the public?

Comment: min.map is nothing more than just allow you to debug, put more code and recheck your console

Comment: @Se0ng11 this is all there is to it its just repeating numerous times for different menu but they are all the same except one please look at update..this are all i include in `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: why are you using an ajaxsetup to create a very specific ajax request params

Comment: my problem is not with the lower part its actually in the upper part when i load it sometimes its ok sometimes its not...the one you saying sir @ArunPJohny can it be the reason for this behavior if so please tell me what to do

Comment: @satinekianne see my answer below

Comment: @Barmar I think the possible execution sequence and the default success handler passed to the ajaxSetup is a good place to start

Comment: @ArunPJohny He hadn't posted the ajaxSetup when I made my earlier comments. That appears to be the "something else going on", as you pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one problem I could see is, look at the following steps

1. `pages/homemenu.php` request is sent
2. `'pages/homecontent.php'` request is sent
3. the left panel request is completed, now since you have an ajax setup along with the default load handler, the handler in ajax setup also fires
4. the middle panel request is completed, so the content is loaded to the middle panel by the default handler, now the success handler in the ajax setup fires so the same content is loaded in the left panel also

So if the middle request is completed after the left request, you will get the same result in both the panels because of the default success handler set in the [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/), but if the left panel request is completed after the middle panel then it look Okay even though you are updating the left multiple times....

```
$('#homemenubutton').click(function () {
    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php');
    $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
});

$('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/mayorscolumn.php');
$('#menuhome').click(function () {
    location.reload(true);
    //$('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/mayorscolumn.php');
    //$('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/imagegallerycolumn.php');
});
```

Comment: sir can i just remove the request and make the code stay the same i will try and i will be back on you on this

Comment: @satinekianne sorry, didn't get you. What do you mean by `i just remove the request and make the code stay the same`? which request do you want to remove

Comment: wait  sir i will try your approach i fail on my approach